# Database query from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, database

I'm very new to the database management world. I have two tables that I'm needing to extract data from; `CUSINFO`, and `CLAIMS`. One table includes columns `NAMEID`, and `NAME`, where `NAMEID` is a code associated to the `NAME` column, which simply states the customer's name. On the other table, I have `NAMEID` again, then a `CLAIMNUM`, which is the claim number assigned to the customer. I need to pull the `NAME` column from `CUSINFO` for all `NAMEID` listed in `CLAIMS`.

```
+--------+------+
| NAMEID | NAME |  
+--------+------+

1 | RAYJ01  | Ray Johnson 
2 | TONYD01 | Tony Danza 
3 | JOES01  | Joe Schmoe 


+--------+----------+
| NAMEID | CLAIMNUM |  
+--------+----------+

1 | RAYJ01  | 2347772 
2 | JOES01  | 2356227
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what you expect and your columns but I guess you are looking for something like this (an inner join):

```
Select ci.Name, cl.CLAIMNUM
From CUSINFO ci
inner join CLAIMS cl on ci.NAMEID = cl.NAMEID
```

Comment: This worked for me. I also updated my question to show the table schema a little better. What would I have to do if I wanted to also return the claim number with those names as well?

Comment: Aha! That was far easier than I thought. I'm sorry for the elementary questions. I was given an old db and told "Go". You've been a big help. Thanks!